# Compare String using tMap

Tags: talend

I am using Talend to prepare dataware.
I want to compare the string with the contents of a column using the tMap component and create a variable to store in the DB. The problem is that the `==` operator does not give the right result (Example: `row2.recipient == "text"?"text":""`       I always get `""`) and if I use `.equals` I get errors when executing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get error if row2.recipient is null, and "==" should not be used when comparing strings.
Correct syntax would be :

```
"text".equals(row2.recipient)?"text":""
```

Then you will prevent NullPointerExceptions.